# Need help with identifying the function of 3 wires in camera flash circuit

Tags: flash, camera

I have this camera flash circuit from a Ricoh AF-70. I’m trying to identify what function the 1,2 &4 wires does in this circuit?

The blue wire is definitely to trigger the high voltage to fire the flash. The other red and black wires the positive and negative of the batteries. Unfortunately because the circuit is so tightly packed I can’t see the label of the transistors.

[image: flash]
[image: circuit diagram]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Check our schematic. Why would there be a switch from C1 to the flash tube? It would be carrying high current at high voltage, and the flash tube acts as a thyratron and need no switch. As for t1 and orange wire, it might be part of switch to turn charging on and off. The green might lead to an LED charge indicator.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Which schematic? Sorry, that was an error, I'v updated the circuit diagram. The charged indicator for the capacitor is indicated by the small neon lamp.